# Run instagram code after specific interval of time

Tags: javascript, ajax, instagram

I want to display the pictures from my Instagram to website. I am successful with the image display part, but when new Images are uploaded with the Tag i have mentioned then I want to display it at without refreshing the browser. I want to just call the code again and again after 1 sec.

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
  clientId: 'fd49a37da9f04a47b046395a5d2a8fb9',
  limit: 17 ,
  get:'tagged',
  tagName:'kdy14',
  after: function () {
    var images = $("#instafeed").find('a');
    $.each(images, function(index, image) {
      var delay = (index * 75) + 'ms';
      $(image).css('-webkit-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('-moz-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('-ms-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('-o-animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).css('animation-delay', delay);
      $(image).addClass('animated flipInX');
    });
  },
  template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" /></a>'
});
feed.run();
```

I want to make this JS run after every 1 sec. How can I so this.

Answer (score 1):

use :

```
setInterval(function(){feed.run();}, 1000);//1000 is 1 s
```

**PS :**  if you want to stop it in some place do this :

```
//first put the interval ID in an a var
   var intervalID = setInterval(function(){feed.run();}, 1000);

//then when you want to stop it just do 
    clearInterval(intervalID);
```

Answer (score 0):

The alternative to `setInterval` is a recursive `setTimeout` function which some people seem to prefer:

```
var timer;
(function looper() {
  feed.run();
  timer = setTimeout(looper, 1000);
}());
```

And to clear it:

```
clearTimeout(timer);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jb4syms2/)